# C# remove the string part "Color []" in the string "Color [ColorName]"

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, string

The title basically sums it all up, but to explain: I have a string which contains "Color [(Color name here)]" and I want to get rid of the "Color[]" so I'm left with the (color name here) part, what would be the best way to remove this? and how would I do this?

Comment: Is "Color" static or an actual color?

Comment: the "Color" is static, the part between the [] is the part that's an actual color name

Comment: I'd recommend using a regular expression: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @EdPlunkett I've tried looking into regular expressions, but I can't figure out what to use

Comment: You can write a regex to get `Color name here` and replace with blank. Is that ok ? can you give an example ?

Comment: I want to be left with the part "(color name here)" so remove the "Color[" and the "]"

Comment: If you'd rather not get the type description in the first place you could simply user Color.Name itself for the named colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var test = "Color [Black]";
var color = Regex.Match(test, @"\[(.*?)\]").Groups[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just do a replace on your strings with some LINQ:

```
var colors = new List<string> { "Color[Green]", "Color[Red]" };
var actualColors = colors.Select(c => c.Replace("Color[", "").Replace("]", ""));
```

Regex is overkill here - all your data to be replaced is completely static.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want it to do?

```
text = text.Substring(text.IndexOf("[")+1).Replace("]", "");
```